# C++ formatted serialization

Tags: c++, component-based, lua, serialization, code-reflection

I've decided it's time to implement serialization in my simple engine but this has caused me many headaches for the past couple of days/weeks. My engine uses an entity/component based approach similar to what is described in the [T=Machine](http://t-machine.org/index.php/2007/09/03/entity-systems-are-the-future-of-mmog-development-part-1/) blog.

To keep it simple, my first goal was to implement serialization of entities. Since I'm going to use Lua for scripting, I thought it would be nice to serialize entities into Lua tables. Unfortunately, I find the information that is available on serialization in C++ is rather scarce. After many days of thinking I found one approach which is working for my implementation and is described [here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/serialize-inherit-no-ptrs.html).

In essence, I have an EntityManager class from which I request new entities. This class holds entity as well as pointers of type BaseComponent from which all components derive. Because I store components as base pointers, I couldn't use a friend class for serialization, but had to make the BaseComponent inherit from a Serializable class, which has pure virtual serialization methods.

So, this is not that bad, I just have to inherit from the Serializable class and implement the serialization method. To support deserialization though, I have to do a few tricks according to the last [link](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/serialize-inherit-no-ptrs.html). That is, I have to include a static object inside each component whose sole purpose is to populate a map from component names to *constructors*. Here is a generic example (and please ignore any possible errors),

```
/* Base.h */
struct Base: public Serializeable{
    static std::map<std::string, std::function<Base*(void)> > deriveds;
    virtual ~Base(void){}
};

/* Derived.h */
template<class T>
struct add_map_entry{
    explicit add_map_entry(std::string name){
        Base::deriveds[name] = [](void) -> Base* {
            return new T;
        };
    }
}

class Derived: public Base{
public:
    int x;
    int y;
    Derived(void){
        std::cout << "Derived created" << std::endl;
    }
    void serialize(std::ostream&);
    static add_map_entry<Derived> adder_;
};
```

Then in the implementation file I also have to initialize the static map of the base class as well as the static object of each derived class.

I find this quite a mess and although it could probably be improved with the use of macros, I can't help to wonder if there are better ways. How do you handle this kind of formatted serialization?

PS: Please don't recommend changing to a more flexible programming language :) !

Comment: This serialization is for saving/loading existing entities? Or it's for creating new entities? I'm using Java for my game, but I found it was easier to create my own serialization methods. Simply creating a `toByteSteam` function that writes out to a passed file handle and a constructor that takes a file handle as an argument. This way, you control exactly what gets written and in what order. The file handle can be passed to multiple entities because they just write their data and leave the stream open. Same for reading entities. So one file can hold all the entities.

Comment: Eventually I want to be able to do both. I've seen your blog posts on how you *assemble* entities by reading a descriptions from custom formatted files. I want to do something similar. Unfortunately, what I'm asking is more implementation specific rather than about the general idea. I think that implementing such serialization in Java is much easier.

Comment: The actual assembly of the entities doesn't use any kind of serialization, which is why I asked. I do use the custom serialization I mentioned in my comment for saving/loading existing entities. For my implementation I read in the entities and their unique IDs in one loop, then I read in their attributes in a second loop. That's simply to avoid some dependency issues. A very basic version of what I'm talking about can be found in an my answer [here](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/25969/7191). You seem to be on the right track and know what you're doing, so I'll leave you alone :)

Comment: I hope I didn't sound offensive. I would definitely like to see how you handle the assembly in your code and if it would be possible to do something similar in C++. I would think you would need at least some kind of reflection to achieve this, no?

Comment: Nope, impossible to offend me, I'm a robot. No reflection needed. I've written about it a few times, the blog posts are the most complete. Perhaps [this](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/49382/how-might-i-script-the-creation-of-clr-objects/49385#49385) answer might be useful too. You're welcome to ping me in chat (with a @byte56 and I'll see a notification) if you want to discuss more about how it's done.

Comment: Why not use a database such as SQLite instead of serialization? It doesn't require a server and can run locally. The only thing you'd need to do is create a table that supports your entity/component structure and retrieve or store the entities and components through SQL.

Comment: @Grieverheart: Have you considered looking into Boost.Serialization? It supports important concepts like versioning (*vital* for games where patches can make old data obsolete without versioning), non-intrusive serialization (not needing to derive from some type), etc.

Comment: I think boost serialization doesn't support formatted output to something like JSON or lua, right? I'm probably gonna use it for save games although I hate boost. Another option of course is to use a reflection library like Mirror, but I'm trying to avoid third party libraries for educational purposes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not saying either your approach is good or not! Just simply note that it's very complex and might later give you a headache if you even need to change simplest things. But there is an issue with your current implementation. C++ compilers doesn't care about the order they initialize static variables. this won't cause that much problem with primitive types (integers/float/pointers/etc.) but it definitely might cause a problem in your case. simply because when `Derived::adder_` is being initialized, `base::deriveds` might not be initialized yet. The solution is to use late initializers, something like providing a function to add a new entry in your Object list, and in that forcing derived function to be initialized. here is your code with my suggestion applied:

```
/* Base.h */
struct Base: public Serializeable{
    static std::map<std::string, std::function<Base*(void)> >* deriveds;
    template <class T> static addEntry(add_map_entry<T>&)
    {
        if (deriveds == nullptr)
            deriveds = new std::map<std::string, std::function<Base*(void)> >();
        (*deriveds)[name] = [](void) -> Base* {
            return new T;
        };
    }
    virtual ~Base(void){}
};

/* Derived.h */
template<class T>
struct add_map_entry{
    explicit add_map_entry(std::string name){
        Base::addEntry(*this);
    }
}

class Derived: public Base{
public:
    int x;
    int y;
    Derived(void){
        std::cout << "Derived created" << std::endl;
    }
    void serialize(std::ostream&);
    static add_map_entry<Derived> adder_;
};
```

if I remember correctly all global variables are guarantied to be initialized to zero before the application starts (correct me if I'm wrong) so you won't have such mentioned problem with this code.

Comment: All statically declared variables (not just globals) will have been initialised before main() is called, yes.

Comment: @TrevorPowell I'm talking about the order of initialization. I mean it's possible to see an adder_ variable is initialized before deriveds variable, and it'll cause a access violation even before main() is called.

Comment: Within a single file order will follow the storage declarations, between files there is no guarantee on which file's variables get initialized first.  IIRC

Comment: @Chunk-e-Yamani Thank you very much for your feedback. You are indeed correct that the way I implemented it in the example code, problems can be caused during static initialization because of the order of initialization. I will definitely check your suggestion if I decide to go with the method I presented. You also mention *it's very complex and might later give you a headache*. Do you have any alternatives in mind which might be less complex?

Comment: @Grieverheart not really :| in fact I've once implemented similar structure, for another experimental project. but I didn't really had to change any thing after the base was complete. though you might want to look into boost library and their serialization mechanism, it has it's own features and drawbacks.